# Consumir un Web Service c# a PHP

Tags: php, c#, webservice

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''Nombre_video'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\streaming.php on line 5

Me aparece este error en la linea 5 podrian ayudarme?

Necesito consumir un web service donde tengo un video (Streaming) esta el video en la carpeta htdocs.
pero no me arroja ningun resultado

Aqui esta el codigo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<?php
include_once 'lib/nusoap.php';
$video = null;
if(isset($_POST) && count($_POST)>0){
    $Nombre_v=$_POST['Nombre_video'];
    $ext=$_POST['extencion'];
    $wsdl="http://localhost:8094/wss.asmx";
    $client = new nusoap_client($wsdl,'wsdl');
    $param = ['Nombre_video'=>$Nombre_v,'extencion'=>$ext];
    $resultado = $client->call('Streaming',$param);
    $result = $video;
```

}
?>

Comment: Bienvenida por favor lee [ask], ¿podrías agregar el fragmento de código donde se genera dicho error?

Comment: Ya lo edite :) Gracias!

Comment: Por favor no agregues tu código como imagen, en cambio como texto queda bien

Comment: Ya pude agregarlo

Comment: Revisa estos detalles: $video es null de principio a fin no lo asignas ni lo pasas a algún método que lo pueda asignar por referencia. Yal final $result = null; porque le asignas el valor de $video. Además $resultado recibe el 'Streaming' ¿En ejecución? o ¿debes ejecutarlo en otro lado? aclara tu espacio de nombres e indica que haces o debieras hacer con los resultados.

Comment: El streaming es de un webservice que contiene un video, localhost, donde se supone que me pide el nombre y la extencion, y no me arroja nada